# Swift IOS 7 notification alert with Options

Tags: ios, swift, ios7

How to add local notification alert with three button like close, remind and remind later.

close will close the alert
remind will open the app and remind later will also open the app and I have to navigate to different tab in my app.

I know we can do this functionality in IOS 8 with category is there any way to implement the same in IOS 7.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just schedule a UILocalNotification and have an AlertView pop up when it's fired off. Here is the code for the AlertView. This is based on your top line requirements

func openAlertView(message:String!)
    {
        let topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let CloseAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
        // Close Alert
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let RemindAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Remind", style: .Default) { (action) in

        //Schedule another notification at the preferred time
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    topController!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
    }
let RemindLaterAction = UIAlertAction(title: "RemindLater", style: .Default) { (action) in

        //Schedule another notification at the preferred time
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    topController!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
}
```